# Pandas - manipulate and combine multiple dataframes with loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, merge

I have a list of dataframes that I would like to perform some basic actions to, then combine into a single dataframe. The my code runs fine, but the step where it should drop rows containing `NaN` in a certain column is not happening. If I run the code on a single dataframe outside of a loop it works fine. How can you process multiple dataframes at once? All column names are the same throughout dataframes:

```
column_names = list(M301)

df_list = [M301,
           M302,
           M303,]

for df in df_list:
    df = df[pd.notnull(df[column_names[0]])]
    df['MACHINE'] = str(df)

result = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the values that you thing are null are not actually null.  This happens a lot when you have strings `'None'` or `'NaN'` instead of `None` and `np.nan`.  This is debugging and not an error in how to think of the problem.  What I mean is that I believe what you are doing should work.  (with the exception of what WeNYoBen pointed out)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, because if I run the code on a single dataframe the `pd.notnull()` works. But to your point, do you know if there's a difference from a processing standpoint between `NaN` and `NaT`? One column are dates, and is idenetified as not a time on the null rows

Comment: `pd.isna`/`pd.isnull`/`pd.notna`/`pd.notnull` all treat `pd.NaT`/`np.nan`/`None` as null.  What I'm suggesting is that in one of you dataframes, you have strings instead of null values.  See if you have any thing equal to `'None'`.

Comment: df['MACHINE'] = str(df) is working fine?